# serializing foreing key variable in update method

Tags: django, serialization, django-serializer

I'm trying to override the update method of a serializer. This serializer have a field 'gear' which is a foreing key of the Trawl table. But when I try to save the updated instance in update method, I get the error:

> ValueError: Cannot assign "2": "Haul.gear" must be a "Trawl"
> instance

This is the serializer:

```
 class HaulTrawlSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
     gear = serializers.IntegerField()
 
     class Meta:
         model = Haul
         fields = ['id', 'haul', 'gear', 'valid', ]

     def update(self, instance, validated_data):
 
         if validated_data:
             for attr, value in validated_data.items():
                 print(attr, value)
                 setattr(instance, attr, value)

             instance.save()
 
         return instance
```

So I try to convert Haul.gear to a Trawl instance changing the update method:

```
     def update(self, instance, validated_data):

         instance.gear = Trawl.objects.get(pk=validated_data.pop('gear'))
 
         if validated_data:
             for attr, value in validated_data.items():
                 print(attr, value)
                 setattr(instance, attr, value)

             instance.save()
 
         return instance
```

And then, the error

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'Trawl'

is thrown and I don't understand it. Why first ask for a Trawl instance, but after ask for a int?

Comment: `gear = serializers.IntegerField(source='gear_id')`

Comment: I am not sure why you do not use a `primarykeyrelatedfield` ? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: @BriseBalloches just my ignorance :) Thanks to both, the two posibilities works and I think I understand why.